# Suppress Console.Write in referenced package

Tags: c#, console-application, nuget-package

In one project, I reference a NuGet package which outputs text to the Console when some of its methods are called.

I would prefer it didn't, as I am writing things to the Console in my own code.

Is there a way to suppress the Console writing happening in that package, but still be able to write to Console myself?

Comment: Is it writing to console (like `Console.Write`) or actually using logging which you happen to have going to console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* use `Console.SetOut` to set the default output to any other `TextWriter` - but still use the original `Console.Out`. Here's a demo of that:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var originalOut = Console.Out;
        Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null);

        LibraryMethod();
        originalOut.WriteLine("This should still go to the console.");
    }

    static void LibraryMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Imagine this were in the referenced package.");
        Console.WriteLine("This isn't going anywhere. It's being discarded.");
    }
}
```

That does work - but it's pretty annoying. I would personally ask the author of the original package to modify the package if possible - it's pretty odd for a library to write to the console by default. It should at least allow you to specify which `TextWriter` to write to.

Comment: Can also use `TextWriter.Null` i guess, which is pretty much the same thing

Comment: @TheGeneral: Ooh, nice - didn't know about that. Will edit that in.

Comment: It turns out, after trying this, that it wasn't using the standard `Console.Out` or `Console.Error` streams. The package being referenced was Tikaondotnet, which uses `IKVM`. So by setting `java.lang.System.setOut(null);` and `java.lang.System.setErr(null);` (yes, in C# code), the output was successfully suppressed.